# Font.Color returns confusing values

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, colors, vsto, add-in

I'm trying to read the color of text in my Office Application Level Plugin via `TextRange.Font.Color.RGB` which should return an int (and does).

But the returned values aren't the ones I would expect.

If my color is...

- 0 0 0 --> I get 0
- 255 0 0 --> I get 255
- 147 205 221 --> I get 14536083
- 146 208 80 --> I get 11916796
- and so on...

Where is the problem here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the value to hex first so it is easy to split it in bytes, the values for red, green and blue:

```
14536083 = 0xddcd93 = 0xdd, 0xcd, 0x93 = 221, 205, 147
```

It is backwards because your machine is little-endian.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks. But this endianess thing worries me a bit: could it be possible that there are other Windows machines out there which work in big-endian? That would mean my Add-In runs erroneous on those machines.

Comment: Not a problem.  If there would ever be such a machine then it would have a different version of Office that implements the RGB property differently.